# cakephpにてphpadminのMySQLの使用について

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

学校の課題で簡単な掲示板を作成しているところです。
そこで質問なのですが、cakephpでphpadminで作成したデータベースを利用するにはどうしたらよろしいですか？
開発環境はeclipseです。

Answer (score 1):

ガイドを読んで下さい。

[CakePHP 3.4 Red Velvet Cookbook データベースの基本](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/orm/database-basics.html)